Displaying Localized Strings
I am working with localization in SwiftUI. I created Localizable file with few entries as shown below:

I have created a LocalizedError as shown below:
enum NewDriverLicenseFormError: LocalizedError, Identifiable {
    
    var id: UUID {
        UUID()
    }
    
    case firstName
   
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .firstName:
            return NSLocalizedString("First name cannot be empty.", comment: "")
    }
}

I change my Preview locale to use Spanish:
#Preview("NewDriverLicenseScreen Spanish") {
    NewDriverLicenseScreen()
        .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "es"))
}

When I run the NewDriverLicenseScreen (View) the First Name is shown in Spanish but the error messages displayed in ValidationSummaryView are not shown in Spanish.
struct NewDriverLicenseScreen: View {
    
    @State private var newDriverLicenseForm = NewDriverLicenseForm()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("First name", text: $newDriverLicenseForm.firstName)
            Button("Submit") {
                if newDriverLicenseForm.validate() {
                    
                }
            }
            
            ValidationSummaryView(errorMessages: newDriverLicenseForm.errorMessages)
        }
    }
}

struct ValidationSummaryView: View {
    
    let errorMessages: [NewDriverLicenseFormError]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(errorMessages) { errorMessage in
            Text(errorMessage.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

Any ideas!

NSLocalizedString is not aware of SwiftUI's EnvironmentValues. It solely operates on the device's locale.
You can add a LocalizedStringKey property to your error type. Giving that to a Text will localise the string correctly, because Text is aware of the EnvironmentValues.
var localisationKey: LocalizedStringKey {
    switch self {
    case .firstName:
        return "First name cannot be empty."
}

This will automatically generate an entry in the string catalog.
Usage:
ForEach(errorMessages) { errorMessage in
    Text(errorMessage.localisationKey)
}

